# Unable to send to this email address in Yahoo! mail

Tags: yahoo-mail

I'm on the non classic interface (the standard gui) I tried to send an email to

`users-digest-subscribe@httpd.apache.org`.

The email address is valid and I'm able to send to it via another client or the older interface, but with the standard gui, I get the message

> Invalid Address:
>
> We cannot find a match for this email address:
>
> `users-digest-subscribe@httpd.apache.org`.
>
> Please use an email address that looks like `user@example.com` or a nickname or a distribution list name from your Yahoo! contacts.

Does anybody know how I can send the email to that email address with the standard Yahoo! mail GUI, and without getting that error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `period` at the end of the email address

```
users-digest-subscribe@httpd.apache.org.
                                       ^
```

It should be `users-digest-subscribe@httpd.apache.org` (no period)

[image: Period makes the email address highlighted in red]

Removing the period gets me a reply from the Apache Digest with the subject

> confirm subscribe to users@httpd.apache.org

Comment: i'll provide a link to our chat here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu   as it mentions related things like the old interface.